# jquery slide to attribute with specific data attribute value

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

Ok, so I have the following nav with absolute urls:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="main-menu">
    <li class="first active"><a href="http://example.com/" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/about.html" title="About">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/portfolio.html" title="Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="example.com/contact.html" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

and then articles with the following data attributes:

```
<article class="row page" id="about" data-url="http://example.com/about.html">
    <div class="one">

    </div>
    <div class="two"

    </div>
</article>
```

and when you click the link in the menu I would like to ignore the fact it is a hyperlink and slide to the current article based on its attribute data-url.

I started with what I think is the obvious:

```
$('#main-menu li a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var pageUrl = $(this).attr('href');

)};
```

and have tried find and animate but then I don't know how to reference the article with data-url="http://example.com/about.html".

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#main-menu li a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var pageUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    var $article = $('article[data-url="' + pageUrl + '"]');
    if ($article.length) {
        $('body').stop(true).animate({
            scrollTop: $article.position().top
        })
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LBUJ8/)

Comment: Thanks! That's great!! 
Out of interest if i wrap a div around the entire site at the outermost layer and then add overflow hidden the slides will not then scroll in. The idea being that you can't scroll using scroll wheel or bar. Is this not the correct way to do this?